# Pyspark dataframe - how to determine which column the error occurred on?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database

Using `Pyspark`, when importing data from data file to a `Azure SQL Db` table, I am getting following error. The error itself is self-explanatory. But the data file and target table have about 100 columns with 75 of them as string columns. And, the error does not specify which column the error is on. **Question**: In `pyspark`, how can we determine which column the error is on?

Error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The given value of type VARCHAR(56) from the data source cannot be converted to type varchar(45) of the specified target column.

**Code**:

```
df = spark.read.csv(".../Test/MyFile.csv", header="true", inferSchema="false")
.............
#write to Azure SQL table. Error occurs here
df.write(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the max length of each column before writing to SQL DB

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.select([F.length(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
df.groupby().max().show()
```

Then you can write an udf/function/use pandas to transpose the row to column